# Making Java Servlet Thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I've been getting mixed up responses on the execution of my API from webpage.

Backtracked a little and found out, Angular was firing it the right way, but the API responded with mixed responses for concurrent requests.

Searched the internet found out Global variables in Java servlet may trigger the abnormal behavior as one thread might access the variable currently being processed by another variable.

So coming to the point I realized `PrintWriter` is creating a problem here. But what I'm experiencing a difficulty with is how to get out of the problem.

And also may be the current problem is not at all related to my conclusions.
Please correct me wherever I've wrongly derived anything wrong.

```
@WebServlet(name = "WorkSpaceDetails", urlPatterns = {"/WorkSpaceDetails"})
public class WorkSpaceDetails extends HttpServlet {

    PrintWriter out;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, Exception {
        String wid = request.getParameter("id");

        try {

            id = Integer.parseInt(wid);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
            out = response.getWriter();
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement prx = null;
            PreparedStatement pry = null;
            ResultSet set = null;

            ResultSetMetaData metaData;
            String query;
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            String WorkSpaceType;
            List<HashMap> completeData = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
            List<String> ColoumnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> Data = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                query = "-";
                conn = boneCPConnectionPool.getConnection();
                prx = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                prx.setInt(1, id);
                set = prx.executeQuery();
                while (set.next()) {
                    WorkSpaceType = set.getString("WorkSpaceType");
                    System.out.println("WorkSpaceType:" + WorkSpaceType);
                    if (WorkSpaceType.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        System.out.println("" + 1);
                        query = "-";
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("" + 0);
                        query = "-";
                    }
                    conn = boneCPConnectionPool.getConnection();
                    pry = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    pry.setInt(1, id);
                    set = pry.executeQuery();
                    metaData = set.getMetaData();
                    int count = metaData.getColumnCount();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                        System.out.println("" + metaData.getColumnName(i));
                        ColoumnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(i));
                    }
                    while (set.next()) {
                        HashMap tmp = new HashMap();
                        for (int i = 0; i < ColoumnNames.size(); i++) {

                            String cname = ColoumnNames.get(i);

                            tmp.put(cname, set.getString(cname));
                            tmp.put("WorkSpaceType", WorkSpaceType);
                        }
                        System.out.println("" + tmp);
                        completeData.add(tmp);
                        generateJson(completeData);
                    }


                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                out.println(e);
            } finally {

                if (conn != null) {
                    try {
                        conn.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
                if (set != null) {
                    try {
                        set.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                    }
                }
                if (prx != null) {
                    try {
                        prx.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                    }
                }
                if (pry != null) {
                    try {
                        pry.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("Error", "BLANK ID");
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void generateJson(List<HashMap> data) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            for (HashMap map : data) {

                Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();

                while (it.hasNext()) {

                    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                    String key = (String) pair.getKey();

                    String value = (String) pair.getValue();
                    if (value == null) {
                        value = "blank";
                    }
                    obj.put(key, value);
                }
            }

            out.println(obj.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        out = response.getWriter();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("Error", "API Protected Get Request");
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WorkSpaceDetails.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        out.println(obj.toString());
        out.close();
        System.out.println("API Protected:Get Request");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        out = response.getWriter();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            try {
                obj.put("Error", "ID NULL");
            } catch (JSONException ex1) {
                Logger.getLogger(WorkSpaceDetails.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            }
            out.println(obj.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            try {
                obj.put("Error", "TOKEN NULL");
            } catch (JSONException ex1) {
                Logger.getLogger(WorkSpaceDetails.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            }
            out.println(obj.toString());
            out.close();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Servlet to get info of a Workspace";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of declaring `PrintWriter out;` as a class member, do it as a local variable inside `processRequest()`, like you're already doing in `doGet()` and `doPost()`. This way, the multiple threads that may access the servlet concurrently won't interfere with each other.

#### UPDATE

It seems that `processRequest()` is only called from `doPost()`, so I suggest you to:

- Get rid of `PrintWriter out` class member
- Declare a local `PrintWriter out` in `doGet()`
- Declare a local `PrintWriter out` in `doPost()`
- Pass `out` as a parameter to `processRequest()`, whose signature may be:

```java
private void processRequest(
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, PrintWriter out);
```

#### UPDATE

- Pass `out` as a parameter to `generateJson()`
- Pass `out` as a parameter to call made to 'generateJson' method at `processRequest()`

`private void generateJson(List<HashMap> data, PrintWriter out);`

`generateJson(completeData, out);`

Comment: If I'll do that, the logic breaks the flow of the data, as the scope restricts to  methods they are defined in. The servlet doesn't provides any response.

Comment: @AkshayR. that's strange. From the code snippet you posted, `PrintStream out` is only used in `processRequest()` method, so there would be no problem in doing as i suggested

Comment: Have updated the code to the functional one. Please check out doget() and dopost() methods too

Comment: @AkshayR. updated my answer. By the way, that class doesn't compile yet

Comment: Brilliant. Did my work and the problem with this solution not working in my case was that an additional method generateJson was requiring out as a parameter and then the parameter needed to be passed in the call made to generateJson at processRequest() method. Would add that to your final answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two of the options you have to fix this issue are as follows:

1. Move `PrintWriter` to local variables inside methods that need it.
2. If you absolutely have to have it as an instance/class variable then use a `ThreadLocal` variable. Using `ThreadLocal` would allow each thread accessing your `servlet` to have its own `PrintWriter` instance.

[ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This would also work what I thought. But didn't in my case. Don't know why. This is what I was searching for, so that I can get my problem solved without much hassles. Thanks anyway.